# Call smart contract via RPC error

Tags: smart-contracts, rpc

I am trying to call a smart contract via RPC, but keep getting this error:

> "Failed to parse the request body: No case matched:\n  At /kind,
>   unexpected string instead of endorsement\n  At /kind, unexpected
>   string instead of seed_nonce_revelation\n  At /kind, unexpected string
>   instead of double_endorsement_evidence\n  At /kind, unexpected string
>   instead of double_baking_evidence\n  At /kind, unexpected string
>   instead of activate_account\n  At /kind, unexpected string instead of
>   proposals\n  At /kind, unexpected string instead of ballot\n  At
>   /kind, unexpected string instead of reveal\n  At /parameters, missing
>   object field entrypoint\n  At /kind, unexpected string instead of
>   origination\n  At /kind, unexpected string instead of delegation"

This is what I am sending:

```
{
  "branch": "BLJWtitW4vnxKaLSyVB4Naybp112MWc3hwifosU8FhzRAh6LcT8",
  "contents": [
    {
      "source": "tz1S8g2w1YCzFwueTNweWPnA852mgCeXpsEu",
      "public_key": "edpkuvD4ebMTaVm7qqKUrh8mJXZGe5TyJNjWNFpSwdM1dLPDsM3wV4",
      "storage_limit": "0000000",
      "gas_limit": "0010000",
      "fee": "0001272",
      "kind": "reveal",
      "counter": "663191"
    },
    {
      "amount": "0000000",
      "source": "tz1S8g2w1YCzFwueTNweWPnA852mgCeXpsEu",
      "destination": "KT1BgA1y2Epm3qDh1HDf2mzjaiAx5hrNngcE",
      "storage_limit": "0000257",
      "gas_limit": "0010100",
      "fee": "0001272",
      "kind": "transaction",
      "counter": "663192",
      "parameters": {
        "string": "votes"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The call is expecting an input of string, you can check out the contract at `KT1BgA1y2Epm3qDh1HDf2mzjaiAx5hrNngcE` on Zeronet.

Would you happen to know what parameters are wrong/missing or some reference that I can compare my call to?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I originated a contract of type `string` in a sandbox, and called it thus:

```
tezos-client -l transfer 0 from bootstrap1 to test_contract -arg '"votes"' --burn-cap 1
```

note the `-l` argument, which will show the RPCs between node and client.
Notably, you will see the following output:

```
>>>>9: http://localhost:18731/chains/main/blocks/head/helpers/scripts/run_operation
  { "operation":
      { "branch": "BLxEpb5UYQAALGNTP8XqwBJra1wxDyGV4yLPLqehpNUCXb7moJK",
        "contents":
          [ { "kind": "transaction",
              "source": "tz1KqTpEZ7Yob7QbPE4Hy4Wo8fHG8LhKxZSx", "fee": "0",
              "counter": "3", "gas_limit": "800000",
              "storage_limit": "60000", "amount": "0",
              "destination": "KT18ynDzyLb659V492GVQXP5ztfq2gXiUaBv",
              "parameters":
                { "entrypoint": "default", "value": { "string": "votes" } } } ],
        "signature":
          "edsigtXomBKi5CTRf5cjATJWSyaRvhfYNHqSUGrn4SdbYRcGwQrUGjzEfQDTuqHhuA8b2d8NarZjz8TRf65WkpQmo423BtomS8Q" },
    "chain_id": "NetXdQprcVkpaWU" }
<<<<9: 200 OK
```

My argument looks like this:

```
{ "entrypoint": "default", "value": { "string": "votes" } } }
```

which is different from yours.

Comment: Thanks, that was it, now it works flawlessly :)